# Seperating Charges in a Cell

Tags: electricity, electrons, physical-chemistry, batteries, protons

Sorry for not being detailed for my question here but how do charges seperate in a cell and when the electrons are pumped out of the battery does it return and become positive ? Yet again sorry if I don't make sense but I'm just wondering how it works.

Comment: You can get an idea how batteries work from articles on the web.

Comment: To what does  the "it" refer, in the second line of your question?

Answer (score 0):

you might be confusing batteries and capacitors. While both always stay relatively neutral, the capacitors store charges on thin metallic sheets separated by dielectric and usually made into rolls to save space while the batteries store chemical energy and a chemical process drives electron current between the terminals. in case of lead battery the negative terminal is connected to the plates made of lead and which can react with sulfuric acid and release electrons which should travel through the circuit, the same reaction produces hydrogen ions that travel through the electrolyte toward the plates made of lead dioxide and meet there with the electrons that traveled through the circuit and getting converted into water while lead dioxide gets converted into lead sulfate. When a lead battery is completely discharged most of its lead dioxide is converted into lead sulfate.